# Is there a problem with protesting Jewish-owned businesses?

Tags: halacha, business, chilul-kidush-hashem

Is there an issue of publicly protesting a Jewish business, such as by picketing or boycotting, being a chilul Hashem? Are there any other (halachic or other) problems? What if you believe that the actions of the Jewish business constitute a chilul Hashem?

Comment: Which Chillul Hashem is bigger?

Comment: Daniel, any reason you think protesting a Jewish-owned business's activity should be different from protesting a Jew's?

Comment: @msh210 I don't necessarily think they should be different. I don't think that I've suggested that I think they're different?

Comment: @Daniel, I ask only because you asked specifically about protesting against a business instead of asking what seems to me to be the more natural question of protesting against any Jew.

Comment: @msh210: it seems to me like protesting a business is a more common thing to do than protesting a person. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @Daniel, could be. Personally, I don't recall the last time I protested against a business, whereas I've protested family members' wrongdoings several times in recent memory.

Comment: @msh210: I'm talking more about protesting publicly. For example picketting or organizing a boycott. Perhaps your answer could address this as well?

Answer (score 1):

*(This answer is to a previous version of the question, though it has some relevance to the current version also.)*

[The *Bavli* (*Arachin* 16:2)](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=5038) says:

> Whence [the rule] that if one sees a despicable thing in his friend then he must admonish him? ― It says [in [*Vayikra* 19:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9920/showrashi/true#v17)], "Admonish".… Is it possibly true even if his face changes [from being shamed in public by the admonishment —*Rashi*]? ― It teaches us, saying [ibid.], "do not bear a sin because of him".

This is codified in [*Rambam*](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=2&perek=6&halocha=8) also, who adds:

> What are these things said about? Matters among people. But about divine matters, if he did not change his ways privately, we embarrass him publicly, publicizing his sin….

I see no reason to think a business owned by a Jew is different: after all, when you protest the business's action, what you're actually protesting is its proprietor's.

Of course, for practical guidance, consult your rabbi rather than relying on what you read on this site.